# usb2 specification - is it backwards compatible

Tags: usb

Say I had usb port on my motherboard that only supports low speed devices, will full speed/ high speed devices not work on the low speed ports but at a lower speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no. There really is no such thing as a low-speed-only host port; it would violate the USB standard.

But even if such a thing did exist, the USB protocol does not support having a host negotiate a device down from full speed to low speed.

Comment: But a high-speed device **will** enumerate at full-speed.  It may not function correctly (e.g. a video camera that needs the full bandwidth) but it should still enumerate, and most devices like hard drives will continue to work at full speed instead of high speed.

Comment: Yes, in fact, a high-speed device *always* identifies itself first as full speed, then negotiates the speed up to high speed if the host supports it.